# How to move one element closer to the other one. CSS

Tags: html, css

I just need a little help with my CSS:
I As you can see in here http://jsfiddle.net/5crwu/ I have some space between `span` and `ul` elements, and I can't find how to lift `ul` up, closer to the `span`. I thought `margin: 0;` will do this, but looks like I'm missing something.

```
.app-technologies {
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.app-technologies span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.app-technologies ul{
    list-style: circle;
    padding-left: 18px;
    margin-top: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to remove the `<br>`, you can give your  and NEGATIVE margin.  It would be `margin:0px 0px -20px 0px;`

The negative bottom margin on the span will pull it up.

Answer (score 2):

I just removed the BR after the SPAN, and the "position: relative" from the span styledef. No more space-between.